# How to automatically loop multiple Ids in Jmeter

Tags: variables, jmeter

I am now trying to use Jmeter.

I have created a http request to receive multiple Ids from one response and used Json extractor to store the Ids.

The stored Ids are like:
id_1:1234
id_2:2234
id_3:3234
id_ALL:1234,2234,3234

Now, I would like to use those Ids in another response, but I don't want to configure the variable every time because there are numbers of id_{ascending number}.

example:

url: http://localhost/{id_1}
method: GET

url: http://localhost/{id_2}
method: GET

url: http://localhost/{id_3}
method: GET

I have tried to use User defined variable like: ${id_${counter}}, but it didn't work. How do I get this operation successfully?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is using [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) configured like:

once done in the ForEach Controller's child(ren) you will be able to refer the "current" id as `${id}`

[image]

If you want to use the current iteration counter you need to wrap everything into [__V() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) like:

[image]

String representation just in case:

```
${__V(id_${__intSum(${__jm__Loop Controller__idx},1,)},)}
```

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)